# Finding maximum of functions of a partition

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a function $u(x)=x^{0.5}$ if $x>0$ and $u(x)=a(-x)^{0.5}$ if $x<0,$ with $u(0)=0$, $a>0$. Let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ with the elements real numbers and $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n>0$. Let $v:P\rightarrow R$, where $P$ are the partitions of $X$, such that $v(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)=u(p_1)+u(p_2)+\cdots+u(p_n)$. How can I find the vector $p\in P$ such that maximizes $v$.
Example, suppose that $X=\{10,9,-1\}$, then $p=(9,9,0)$ maximizes $v$, but I do not know how to extend it to any number of elements of $X$.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. $v$ is a function from the partitions of $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but the elements of a partition are sets, whereas $u$ is defined on what looks to be real numbers.

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to make the notation and I have a mistake in the question. The set $P$ is conformed by the sum of the elements of subsets of the partition of $X$. Let me clarify with the example. Given $X=\{10,9,-1\}$ we have five vectors $(10,9,-1),(9,9,0),(10,8,0),(19,0,-1),(18,0,0)$ then I need to find which one of these vectors maximizes $v$. Clearly $v(9,9,0)=u(9)+u(9)+u(0)$ is the maximum value. For $n=4$ we have by the Bell number 15 vectors and I need to find the vector that maximizes $v$. Hope, now I make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

Note that  for $x,y \geq 0, \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{x+y}$ with equality iff one is $0$ (square both sides to confirm). The same result extends to any finite sum of square roots. so in your example, we would actually maximize the value by partitioning into $\{\{10\},\{9\},\{-1\}\}$, giving us the vector $(10,9,-1)$. Now you just need consider the case for $y < 0 < x$, which I believe depends on the value of $a$.

Comment: My question is that we can discard almost all the elements and get only two vectors that will be optimal. For instance, let $X=\{10,9,-1,-2\}$, I have simulated and depending on the value of $a$ two vectors can be optimal which are: $(9,7,0,0)$ or $(10,9,0,-3)$ if $a>a_0$ then the first vector is the optimal and if $a<a_0$ the second one is the optimal, both among the all 52 possible partition subsets. I think the result is general, but I do not know how to prove it for any $n$.

Comment: What is the mathematical name of this kind of problem? Is it NP complete?

Comment: How is $(10,9,0,-3)$ better than $(10,9,-1,-2)$? Likewise, how is $(9,7,0,0)$ better than the same vector?

Comment: I have a mistake. If $a>0.291$ then $\sqrt[ ]{8}+\sqrt[ ]{8}$ is the largest value over the other 14 vectors.While if $a<0.291$ then $\sqrt[ ]{10}+\sqrt[ ]{9}-a \sqrt[]{3}$ over the other 14 vectors. Therefore, the optimal vectors are $(8,8,0,0)$ or $(10,9,0,-3)$.